# C++ stoi not resolving using eclipse to compile

Tags: c++, eclipse

This code fails to compile with an error that it can't resolve stio. Have I made some newbie mistake here?

Eclipse Version: 3.8.1 Mint KDE should all be up to date.

GCC Version: gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) 5.4.0 20160609

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string numberGuessed;
    int intNumberGuessed = 0;
    int answer = 0;

    answer = (rand() % 100) + 1;

    do {
        cout << "Guess a number "; // prints !!!Hello World!!!
        getline(cin, numberGuessed);
        intNumberGuessed = stoi(numberGuessed);
        cout << "You guessed "<< numberGuessed << endl;
        cout << "You are not correct. Try again" << endl;
    } while (answer != intNumberGuessed);

cout << "you got it";
return 0;
}
```

The error message.

```
16:39:14 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project Hello2 ****
make all 
Building file: ../src/Hello2.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/Hello2.d" - 
MT"src/Hello2.d" -o "src/Hello2.o" "../src/Hello2.cpp"
../src/Hello2.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
 ../src/Hello2.cpp:27:40: error: ‘stoi’ was not declared in this scope
  intNumberGuessed = stoi(numberGuessed);
                                    ^
make: *** [src/Hello2.o] Error 1
src/subdir.mk:18: recipe for target 'src/Hello2.o' failed

16:39:14 Build Finished (took 613ms)
```

Comment: Looks like your compiler is too old recognizing it. Can you tell your exact version of gcc please?

Comment: Note: Eclipse is not compiling anything. It is calling out to a compiler like g++, clang++ or cl.exe to do the actual compilation.

Comment: gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) 5.4.0 20160609

Comment: That's rather old. Latest gcc atm is 8.2 IIRC.

Comment: I can't find a way to update GCC to 8.2 on my Mint linux. I also have not found where to set the compiler flags on Eclipse. The life of a newbie.

Comment: @DouglasEKnapp You can set additional compiler flags in your C++-project build properties.

Comment: On RedHat derived distros you'd install [devtoolset-7](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/devtoolset-7/).

Comment: @DouglasEKnapp I added a link to my answer, which explains in detail how to set the compiler flags.

Comment: GCC5.4 should be more than sufficient to get C++11 support.

Answer (score 2):

The [`std::stoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) function is available since the c++11 standard.

Apparently your compiler version of GCC is too old, to take c++11 as the current default standard.

You may try to specify the `-std=c++11` or `-std=c++0x` compiler flags, or update your gcc compiler to one of the most recent versions.

Here's a [link](https://codeyarns.com/2014/01/14/how-to-change-compiler-options-of-build-in-eclipse-cdt/) explaining in detail how to set the compiler flags.

[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/466651/how-do-i-use-the-latest-gcc-on-ubuntu) might help you with updating your compiler version to the latest.

Comment: Addendum: Recent Eclipse versions (Current most recent is 4.8, so at 3.8 the asker is about 6 years out of date and this comment may not apply) have a drop-down that allows setting the desired standard at *Project->Properties->C/C++ Build->Settings->Dialect*.